# How to get full path of file to read it & save its data in database?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am trying to read an Excel file & upload its data to database using Spring4 + POI.

Flow for this functionality is:

1. JSP (select excel file)
2. Get that file on controller (with complete path)
3. Pass to service for extracting data.

Problem ::
 I am getting only file name on controller but I need complete path of that file.

Eg: I get `Book.xls` in controller but I want `D:\Book.xls` in controller to read its data.

I need to pass this fullpath to -->

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Book.xls"));
```

Because of "Book.xls" it gives me Exception:
Exception :Book.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)

JSP code:

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

can you please help me to get path of selected file.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons it is not allowed to to upload file with its full path ( client directory structure )

Rather what you can do is,

1. Upload file ( you have that, already uplaoded)
2. Store it in server side location
3. Read it from there

If required I will give code for that, but first try this

You can use apache commons-io's **copyFile** api for that..

thanks

**Update :- My working Code**

```
    for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
        System.out.println(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()+"       "+multipartFile.getContentType()+" "+multipartFile.getName());
        try {
                multipartFile.transferTo(new File(filePathToSave+"/"+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here 'filePathToSave' is path where u want to save file, again read from same path

Comment: I am trying to get this file on controller using below code.

Comment: I am trying to get this file on controller using below code.     List<MultipartFile> files = travelExcelForm.getFiles();

  List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  
  if(null != files && files.size() > 0) {
   for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {

    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(); }}    here also am getting only file name, not file.    if it is possible, can you mail me code for this.